# How do I properly call a function inside another function in c?

Tags: c, function

I'm, trying to make a switch statement that will call a function depending on what the user entered, but every time I put everything that needs to be done into a function it doesn't work properly. Am I actually calling it properly?

```
/*two functions I am using*/

void MoveUp(char *move, int *place, char temp[ ], struct Player *Data, struct board           room[ ]);
void Movement(char *move, int place, char temp[ ], struct Player Data, struct board room[ ]);

/*function calling MoveUp function which actually does all the work*/
void Movement(char *move, int place, char temp[], struct Player Data, struct board room[ ])
{
     printf("Please Enter move: ");
     *move = getchar();
     getchar();

 if(*move == 'k')
 {  
         MoveUp(&*move, &place, temp, &Data, room);
     }


 else if(*move == 'q'){DataDisp(Data);}
}
```

the function `MoveUp` has to modify the variables but Movement only modifies char move.
When I put everything that's outside inside the `MoveUp` function in the if statement(which is meant to be a switch :P) everything works properly but not when I put it in the function.

Comment: The operators `&` and `*` cancel each other out.  `Moveup(move ...` is just as good.

Comment: If I was you, I would consider switching to C++ ...

Comment: well, this is hw so I kinda have stick with C.

Comment: @user2485710: That "advice" makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

If these functions are supposed to be modifying `struct Player` then the fact that you call `Movement()` with `struct Player Data` means that your making a copy and the changes you make will be thrown away when you return.

Change it to a pointer:

```
void Movement(char *move, int place, char temp[ ], struct Player * Data, struct board room[ ]);
```

Comment: so when I am calling the MoveUp function how should I pass the variables so that Moveup can modify them?

Comment: There's no such thing as a reference in C.

Comment: Right now in MoveUp you are passing `Data` by a pointer to a `struct Player` so that will allow you to modify it.

Answer (score -1):

Your function has variables of the kind:

```
void MoveUp(char *move, int *place, char temp[ ], struct Player *Data, struct board           room[ ]);
void Movement(char *move, int place, char temp[ ], struct Player Data, struct board room[ ]);
```

char*, and the other function takes that same type, so you must call it with:

```
MoveUp(move, place, ...);
```

Without the & or *

Comment: No, this is wrong. It's not a must. It's certainly un-idiomatic and horrible to call a function with `&*ptr`, but since `*ptr` is an lvalue, and `&` is the "inverse" operator of `*`, the two are equivalent. See the other answer.